# It does not work in the construction AWK?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "'"$QUERY_IMSI_END"'";
} 
{
split($0,a,";")
}
END {print a[3],a[2],a[1]}'
```

It does not print the result array, which is formed from QUERY_IMSI_END. How to make the right design?

Comment: Any chance on getting the result set from $QUIERY_IMSI_END to help in troubleshooting?  That is, re-write the issue replacing "$QUIERY_IMSI_END" with the resulting data set, preferably just a subset of the data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` reads it's input from stdin. But `print` prints the output to stdout.

I guess you want this:

```
echo "${QUERY_IMSI_END}" | awk -F';' '{print $3, $2, $1}'
```

Note that you can pass a field separator different from the default one using `-F`. An explicit `split()` isn't necessary.

Comment: And how can within AWK print?

Comment: You can, you can pass it as a variable.

Comment: @123 What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
QUERY_IMSI_END="Some;thing;is;wrong"
awk -F";" '{print $3,$2,$1}' <(echo $QUERY_IMSI_END)
```

or if you want to pass that variable to awk. But remember that awk reads from STDIN where it expects a read buffer or handle. So you have to pass a file or buffer handle as input.

```
awk -v Variable=$QUERY_IMSI_END -F";" '{split(Variable,array,";"); print a[3],a[2],a[1]}' file1
```

Comment: why the downvote? Is there something wrong with the code?